# elisp: if symbol has a value return it otherwise return nil

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

if I use this I get an error because `c` is never set.

```
(if (symbol-value c)
    c
  nil)
```

my problem is that I have a list with containing `symbols` and some of them are `set` to some value, I want to construct a list with their values and `nil`s

```
(setq a "x")
(setq b "y")
(setq l '(a b c))
```

so from `l` I want construct a list with `("x" "y" nil)`.
I think this should be some thing so simple

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(setq a "x")
(setq b "y")
(setq l (mapcar (lambda (x)
                  (and (boundp x) (symbol-value x)))
                '(a b c)))
```

Comment: Thank you phils. I missed that primitive predicate `boundp`. and was searching functions with "symbol" string in `apropos`.

Comment: FWIW, an `apropos-documentation` search for `symbol` does include `boundp`, but it's a bit of a needle in a haystack. The elisp manual is a bit easier -- see "Void Variables: Symbols that lack values." under "Variables".